# Check if there is the same object in Core Data relationship

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, core-data

I have 2 kinds of NSManagedObject subclass - "Subject" and "TimeOfSchedule". Entity Subject is connected with TimeOfSchedule

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) TimeOfSchedule *timeOfSubject;
```

In my TableView i am filling cell with time from an array, where i fetched this data from Core Data

```
TimeOfSchedule *objectDate = [timesArray objectAtIndex:(long)indexPath.row];
```

but if there is such TimeOfSchedule which is connected with Subject, or Subject has the same object with relation, I want to fill the cell in another way. How can I do such chek or verification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, fetching from Core Data to fill an array is not a good idea. You should explore the `NSFetchedResultsController` API and use that instead.

Second, once you have retrieved the object for your table view cell you can do the check simply in the same way you would check the existence of any other object in Objective-C.

```
if (objectDate.subject) {
  // dequeue cell for displaying subject
}
else {
  // dequeue cell for displaying only the date 
}
```

Comment: I agree with Mundi, I would go so far as to say you are **far** better off refactoring now, remove the array and talk with Core Data directly.  That is how it is intended to be used.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra why? it is very easy to make an array, and work with it

Comment: @user3224534 You are doing the same work twice, once with the database, once with your array. You are wasting CPU time and memory while at the same time increasing the probability of bugs. Not smart.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to fill arrays in loading time, you can always make a call to the data base to see if any object is related with another.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Subject"];
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeOfSubject == %@",objectDate];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *matches = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if ([matches count]) { // Do Something;
        } else { // Do Something Else
        }
```

Hope it helps.